# Align image corners to video corners in Blender VSE

Tags: video-sequence-editor, image

I want to add 3 images to 3 corners of a video but I don't want to calculate the correct position every single time. Currently the bottom-left corner is the only one that works as I want, for all the other corners I need to calculate something like (video.width - image.width). Which is easy but it gets really annoying when you're adding a bunch of images with various sizes that could be easily aligned by just moving the origin from bottom-left to top-right.

Is there a way to say "align the top-right of the image with the top-right of the video" in Blender Video Sequence Editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is currently a way.

It is an easy task for an addon, so I made one. You can get a copy of it from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sambler/addonsByMe/master/sequencer_alignment.py), just save the link to disk, then in blenders preferences under addon click Install From File and select the script you just saved. Once enabled you will find a panel in the sequencer properties <kbd>N</kbd> with alignment options.

Currently it will align the selected strips to the top, left, bottom or right of the frame. I was just thinking that I could add align to active strip as well as centre, so it may also have those options by the time you see this.